# How to indent entire textPara in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have an SVG with some flowed text that has a hierarchy to it. My text currently looks like this:

[image: actual]

But I'm trying to make it so the second paragraph is fully indented some X units, like so:

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this using a `flowRoot` element which doesn't seem to be too well-documented. I've tried transforming the `flowPara`, surrounding it in a group and transforming that, adding an `x` attribute, and various other random attributes/styles.

The relevant `flowRoot` is as follows:

```
<flowRoot id="flowRoot5170" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" xml:space="preserve">
  <flowRegion id="flowRegion5172">
    <rect height="877.14288" id="rect5174" width="691.42859" x="25.714285" y="60.933632"/>
  </flowRegion>
  <flowPara id="flowPara5176">First Line</flowPara>
  <flowPara id="flowPara5178">Second Line really long line aligned with first ones</flowPara>
</flowRoot>
```

And the full SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg height="297mm" id="svg5162" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" sodipodi:docname="test_inkscape.svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 744.09448819 1052.3622047" width="210mm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs id="defs5164"/>
  <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" borderopacity="1.0" id="base" inkscape:current-layer="layer1" inkscape:cx="375" inkscape:cy="520" inkscape:document-units="px" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2" inkscape:window-height="1001" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-width="1680" inkscape:window-x="0" inkscape:window-y="23" inkscape:zoom="0.35" pagecolor="#ffffff" showgrid="false"/>
  <metadata id="metadata5167">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
        <dc:title/>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g id="layer1" inkscape:groupmode="layer" inkscape:label="Layer 1">
    <flowRoot id="flowRoot5170" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" xml:space="preserve">
      <flowRegion id="flowRegion5172">
        <rect height="877.14288" id="rect5174" width="691.42859" x="25.714285" y="60.933632"/>
      </flowRegion>
      <flowPara id="flowPara5176">First Line</flowPara>
      <flowPara id="flowPara5178">Second Line really long line aligned with first ones</flowPara>
    </flowRoot>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The `flow*` elements are probably under-documented because they are for SVG 1.2, which is not finished. Unless you are exporting to a different format, you probably want to avoid flowing text in the first place, since it's hard to predict support in other viewers.

Comment: @Scribblemacher I did read that this is an Inkscape-specific implementation (which is unfortunate). Inkscape works fine since I'm converting from SVG to PDF/PNG in my application.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<flowRoot id="flowRoot5170" style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:40px;line-height:125%;font-family:Sans;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1" xml:space="preserve">
    <flowRegion id="flowRegion5172">
        <rect height="877.14288" id="rect5174" width="691.42859" x="25.714285" y="60.933632"/>
    </flowRegion>
    <flowPara id="flowPara5176">First Line</flowPara>
    <flowPara id="flowPara5178">Second Line really long line aligned with first ones</flowPara>
</flowRoot>
```

Comment: @Luciano: I edited the post to reveal the hidden HTML.

Comment: @Raja: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Please [edit] your answer to elaborate why it works.